# Full timestamp with high resolution in C on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows-7, timestamp

In my software, traces are produced, for logging purpose (in a Database). Every trace has to have a timestamp, but full date and time and millisecond or finer precision. When I use `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFreq`, I don't get the full timestamp, like `YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss:ms`. It just gives the timespan since the computer was started.

```
Time = count.QuadPart*1000*1000/performance_counter_frequency.QuadPart;
```

How can I get sub-millisecond timestamps including date?

My platform is Windows 7.

Comment: So... what language, and lib are you using?

Comment: Since you mention `QueryPerformanceCounter` I'm assuming Windows is your target.  If so, you can use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`, see:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work by Windows 7..